# GridView with varying cell sizes, Launcher WP8 style

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-gridview, android-launcher

**The problem**

I want to get a special UI, which resembles the Windows 8 Tiles UI, having cells of different sizes on top of each other.

Something like this:

```
AABB
AACC
AADD
AADD
```

each letter represents a part of its cell, so cell A is 2x4 , cell B and cell C take 2x1 each , and cell D is 2x2.

An good example would be [Laucher 8](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lx.launcher8pro2&hl=en).

I don't want to use grid layout.

I am using GridView and I am not being able to achieve above layout using GridView.

**Question**

```
1. I have a framelayout as the items in the adapter.
   Using Linear Layout instead of adapter supporting view will certainly 
   make it boring
   or
   May be I am wrong about Linear Layout.
2. Can such a layout be achieved through GridView.
3. How [Laucher 8][2]. is achieving that.
```

**EDIT**

```
My problem was solved using https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/ . Google's
staggeredViewGridLayoutManager didn't help may be because I didn't found
it's good usage documentation and I was not able to layout the items in the 
Layout in my desired location.
```

Comment: "I don't want to use grid layout" -- why? It will help others give you better suggestions if you explain why an obvious choice is something that you do not want. "Can such a layout be achieved through GridView." -- no. `GridView` cells are of uniform size. "How [Laucher 8][1] is achieving that" -- use **`uiautomatorviewer`** and find out. Beyond that, what you are referring to is generally called a "staggered grid", and it is possible to create one using `RecyclerView` and various open source libraries.

Comment: Thank you @CommonWare. GridLayout is very new Layout and Im afraid it will not run in old android versions. Didnt knew about uianimatorViewer.

Comment: "GridLayout is very new Layout" -- it has been around for four years. "Im afraid it will not run in old android versions" -- the `gridlayout-v7` backport supplied in the Android Support package works back to API Level 7, which covers 99+% of active Android devices.

Comment: @CommansWare, Somewhere in internet I mistakenly read that Gridlayout supports API 17. My bad. If I use GridLayout, I will have to define each and every position and sizes of every tile. Also I am working with around 100+ tiles. Also my mobile API level is below 16 so, I was not able to use uiautomatorviewer. But I get the idea.

Comment: @dberm22 no its not duplicate. I do not want my layout as that of pinterest style.

Comment: @Computergodzilla Really? Because you copied and pasted much of his question.

Comment: @dbrem2, Yeah I did. :). Reusability.. But question is different. Thank you. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at [StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid). It's not exactly what you want, but you may be able to modify it to your needs.

Also possible, is this  [pinterest-style](https://github.com/huewu/PinterestLikeAdapterView) GridView

You might also want to reach out to the dev of [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gridsizefree). He might have some answers for you.